# Open ng-bootstrap modal from all components

Tags: angular

I use ng-bootstrap modal for a popup. so I created one separate component for all popup. now I want to open modal from other components button click.

I tried the @output method. but I did not get success.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use @output you need to use NgbModal in ng-bootstrap

```
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

you can check the ng-bootstrap documentation for details about your problem:

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)